# Custom JavaScript in 'MediaWiki:Common.js' is not working

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, wiki

1. I fresh installed MediaWiki on my own server (latest version)
2. I tried adding some JavaScript code to `MediaWiki:Common.js`
3. In `localsettings.php`, `$wgAllowUserJs` is set to true
4. I also tried adding the JavaScript to `User:Admin/vector.js` and `User:Admin/common.js`
5. I cleared cache/cookies, used different browsers, JavaScript enabled, tried different computers

The JavaScript code does not work at all. I viewed source and it's not there.

```
<!-- BEGIN Tynt Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.location.protocol=='http:'){
        var Tynt=Tynt||[];Tynt.push('cAe5WESDOr4BZUacwqm_6r');Tynt.i={"ap":"Read more:"};
        (function(){var s=document.createElement('script');s.async="async";s.type="text/javascript";s.src='http://tcr.tynt.com/ti.js';var h=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);})();
    }
</script>
<!-- END Tynt Script -->
```

Comment: Do not include `<script>` and `</script>` on the *.js page - it will be included as a separate JS file, not inline in the HTML page. Also, you don't need `$wgAllowUserJs` for MediaWiki pages (there is a separate setting for that, but it is on by default).

Comment: Note that [$wgAllowUserJs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowUserJs) enables User:<Username>/common.js while MediaWiki:Commons.js is controlled by [$wgUserSiteJs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseSiteJs)

Comment: @Tgr Could you please add your comment as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 5):

Do not include `<script>` and `</script>` on the *.js page - it will be included as a separate JS file, not inline in the HTML page.

Note that you don't need `$wgAllowUserJs` for javascript pages in the `MediaWiki` namespace, only for ones in the `User` namespace. (There is a separate setting called [`$wgUseSiteJs`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseSiteJs) for enabling scripts in the `MediaWiki` namespace, but it is on by default).

Comment: it's $wgUseSiteJs, not User... the link in this answer points at the right page, though.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. (Did you know [you can just edit the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)?)